# How to convert radio button list value to bit in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is code for inserting value to database but Radio button list value is not converted and inserting failed.

```
using (SathsurEntities se = new SathsurEntities())
{    
    tbl_Events user = new tbl_Events();   

    user.Event_name = txtEventName.Text;
    user.Event_date = Convert.ToDateTime(txtEventDate.Text);    
    user.Image_url = lblimg.Text;    
    user.Is_free_entry = Convert.ToBoolean(rblEntry.SelectedValue);    
    user.Booking_url = txtBooking.Text;

    se.AddTotbl_Events(user);

    se.SaveChanges();

    Response.Write("Event Added Successfuly!");    
}
```

Comment: What you get in rblEntry.SelectedValue ?

Comment: If selected value is not "True" or "False" you cannot convert. Have you debugged it and see what comes?

Comment: <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblEntry" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>

Comment: value 1 or 2 are passing..

Answer (score 0):

this is where you might use an extension method along the lines of this:

```
  public static class BooleanExtensions
    {
        public static bool ToBool(this string value)
        {
            bool result = false;
            switch (value.ToLower().Trim())
            {
                case "y":
                case "yes":
                case "1":
                    result = true;
                    break;
                case "n":
                case "no":
                case "0":
                    result = false;
                    break;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

usage:

```
var value="0";
Console.Write(value.ToBool());
```

Should output false.

to use in your project, include that class above. You would use this in your code example like so

```
using (SathsurEntities se = new SathsurEntities())
{    
    tbl_Events user = new tbl_Events();   

    user.Event_name = txtEventName.Text;
    user.Event_date = Convert.ToDateTime(txtEventDate.Text);    
    user.Image_url = lblimg.Text;    
    user.Is_free_entry = rblEntry.SelectedValue.ToBoolean();    
    user.Booking_url = txtBooking.Text;

    se.AddTotbl_Events(user);

    se.SaveChanges();

    Response.Write("Event Added Successfuly!");    
}
```

Comment: booleans are logically bits already since they have only two states: true or false. When you assign these values to an entity to store, the  entity framework will convert these to bits.

Comment: You should read about extension methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx
Make a new file, put the BooleanExtensions class in that file. So long as that class is visible to your code, then all strings will have access to that ToBoolean() method.

Comment: Be careful with this--extension methods are nice because you can use them again later, but if you forget that the string "true" has not been accounted for, you will get `false` when you do "true".ToBool(). I would suggest throwing an error if you get an input you haven't accounted for yet--that could save you debugging time later.  BUT, if you do that, you'll need to add "2" to your false list since you have assigned the false button the value "2" (or you can change that value).  ...and "2" becoming false is a little... odd.

Comment: @PhatRat I agree. A contract should be added to the method to ensure only values that can be binary can be converted to t/f , or values that you want converted. Which is sort of why I left it open but it should have been mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

a simple answer,

```
private bool value=true;
if (rblEntry.SelectedValue == "1")
{
     value = true;
}
else if (rblEntry.SelectedValue == "2")
{
     value = false;
}
user.Is_free_entry = value;
```

Comment: This could be simplified to a ternary expression. My answer below makes it easier to reuse across ones application and more versatile as it handles other possibilities for binary values.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only want to have two value , should have 'true' and 'false', it's enough .
if you have more value or more type ,you can use the type of byte or int ....
the you should use the if ... else ... or switch ... case ...

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblList" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="True" Value="True" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="False" Value="False"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

var a = Convert.ToBoolean(rblList.SelectedValue);
```

or

```
    var a = Convert.ToInt16(rblList.SelectedValue);
    var retValue = string.Empty;
    switch (a)
    {
        case 0:
            //"you want have"
            break;
        case 1:
            //"you want have"
            break;
        case 2:
            //"you want have"
            break;
        default:
            //"you want have"
            break;
    }
```

or

```
    if (a == 0)
    {
        //"you want have"
    }
    else if (a == 1)
    {
        //"you want have"
    }
    else if (a == 2)
    {
        //"you want have"
    }
    else
    {
        //"you want have"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`user.Is_free_entry = rblEntry.SelectedValue == "1";`

OR

`user.Is_free_entry = rblEntry.SelectedValue != "2";`

If you can guarantee that all you ever get is either 1 or 2, then these are identical. If you want to try and catch other values, then the first (== "1") emphasizes that you ONLY get true when the value is 1 and you get false for all other values.  The second (== "2") says you ONLY get false if the value is 2 and you get true for all other values. Thus, you can set a default on what to do if you get odd values.  If you want to detect odd values and throw an exception or do other error handling, then you'll want to go with Vikas Rana's suggestion, but with an additional `else`

Comment: If you can make the "false" value equal to 0 instead of 2, then you can also do `user.Is_free_entry = Convert.ToBoolean(rblEntry.SelectedValue);`